# Would this question have been on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I saw a question the other day on a different SE site

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/what-is-the-name-of-this-series

It is about a video series identification. It got it's answer none-the-less, but technically it's not really about biology so some people think it doesn't belong there

Would this question have been on-topic here? What if a video was neither a movie nor part of a tv series?

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the **detail** of the question, if the "video series" was shown on TV (or was a movie) then as a general rule it would have been on topic.

I guess, as an edge case, it *might* be on-topic if it was widely available on VHS/DVD etc.

**If it was not...then the answer would be NO.**

In it's current *form* I would tend to think that it's missing some information that would make it a really **quality** question.

Our "Identify-X" help guidance can be found [**at this link**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Some missing information that could have been added:

- An approximate showing/release date (we don't know when you were in school).
- Original Language
- Country of Origin (I'm assuming US but it's not clear)

Comment: agreed.  I think the person on the other site got lucky that someone knew what it was.  we would want this other information so that those that want to dig, can